# Android Proximity alert is not firing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, proximity

I am trying to set up Proximity alert below is my code but Its not firing at all

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(GMapsActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
locationManager.addProximityAlert(mNavigationDatas.get(CURRENT_INDEX).startCordinates.latitude,
                        mNavigationDatas.get(CURRENT_INDEX).startCordinates.longitude, 100f, -1, pendingIntent);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_PROXIMITY_ALERT); 
registerReceiver(new ProximityBroadcastListener(), filter);
```

Permissions are as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I am sending Mock location to test on real device Android v4.1.2 mock location follows correct path but broadcast listener is not called

```
public class ProximityBroadcastListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
        final Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

        if (entering) {
            String instruction = mNavigationDatas.get(CURRENT_INDEX).drivingInstuctions;
            instruction = instruction.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
            Log.e("", instruction);
            tts.speak(instruction, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            Toast.makeText(context, "entering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            locationManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntent);
            CURRENT_INDEX++;
            locationManager.addProximityAlert(mNavigationDatas.get(CURRENT_INDEX).startCordinates.latitude,
                    mNavigationDatas.get(CURRENT_INDEX).startCordinates.longitude, 100f, -1, pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(context, "exiting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: Can you attach the logs when you send the mock location?

Comment: I am using the same coordinates to mock location that I used to display the route and myLocation pointer moves over the same path and I am sending mock location through another app

Comment: When you send the mock location through another app is the listener registered or it gets unregistered when this app goes in the background?

Comment: No its always registered I used the sample of android mock location and I am not removing listener right now when my app goes in background

Comment: When you change the mock location are there any logs appearing from location manager?

Comment: nope also I didn't even implemented Logs

Comment: Could you try PendingIntent.getBroadcast(GMapsActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); ?

Comment: already tried with that but no effect :(

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would suggest registering the BroadcastReceiver before adding the proximity alert. If your device is already at that location, it may fire the intent before your receiver is ready to listen for it.

You may also want to check that your receiver is registered correctly by manually firing the PendingIntent, for instance through the AlarmManager, a notification or simply by pressing a button.

If none of this works, consider experimenting with a physical device as there are some problems with location events on the emulator. For instance, [due to a bug in the emulator](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27272), the time offset in incoming locations is set to midnight, so your location criteria will likely not match it.